# ways to express concurrency without thread

Tags: multithreading, programming-languages, multiple-languages

I am wondering about how concurrency can be expressed without an explicit thread object, not the implementation, which probably would use threads or thread pools, but the language design related issues.

Q1: I wonder what would be lost if there was no thread object, what couldn't be done in such a language?

Q2: I also wonder about how this would be expressed, what ways were proposed or implemented as alternatives or complements to threads?

Comment: There is a large number of ways to express concurrency, including tasks, actors, parallel loops, various parallel enumerables etc. (And those are just the ones I know from C#.) I think that a question asking to list them all is way too broad.

Comment: @svick Maybe, but I think it's not all that broad. Isn't the parallel enumerable just a specialization of a parallel loop? Wouldn't then parallel enumerable be a footnote in loop parallelization?

Answer (score 0):

one possibility is the MPI-programm-model (GPU as well)

lets say you have the following code

```
for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    work(i);
}
```

the "normal" thread-based way would be the separation of the iteration-range into multiple subsets. So something like this

Thread-1:

```
for(int i=0; i < 50; i++) {
    work(i);
}
```

Thread-2:

```
for(int i=50; i < 100; i++) {
    work(i);
}
```

however in MPI/GPU you do something different.
the idea is, that every core execute the same(GPU) or at least
a similar (MPI) programm. the difference is, that each core uses
a different ID, which changes the behavior of the code.

mpi-style: (not exactly the MPI-syntax)

```
int rank = get_core_id();
int size = get_num_core(); 
int subset = 100 / size;
for (int i = rank * subset;i < (rand+1)*subset; i+) {
    //each core will use a different range for i
    work(i);
}
```

the next big thing is communication. Normally you need to use all of the synchronization-stuff manually. MPI is message-based, meaning that its not perfectly suited for classical shared-memory modells (every core has access to the same memory), but in a cluster system (many cores combined with a network) it works excellent. This is not only limited to supercomputers (they use basically only mpi-style stuff), but in the recent years a new type of core-architecture (manycores) was developed. They have a local so called Network-On-Chip, so each core can send/receive messages without having the problem with synchronization.

MPI contains not only simple messages, but higher constructs to automatically scatter and gather data to every core.
Example: (again not MPI-syntax)

```
int rank = get_core_id();
int size = get_num_core();
int data[100];
int result;
int results[size];
if (rank == 0) { //master-core only
   fill_with_stuff(data);
}
scatter(0, data); //core-0 will send the data-content to all other cores
result = work(rank, data); // every core works on the same data
gather(0,result,results); //get all local results and store them in 
                          //the results-array of core-0
```

an other solutions is the openMP-libary
here you declare parallel-blocks. the whole thread-part is done by the libary itself

example:

```
//this will split the for-loop automatically in 4 threads
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(4)
for(int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    work(i);
}
```

the big advantage is, that its fast to write. thats it
you may get better performance with writing the threads on your own, 
but it takes a lot more time and knowledge about synchronization